Global sections of $E \to M$ with measurable coefficients
I'm reading Demailly's Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry and I stumbled upon the following paragraph.

Now, assume that $M$ is oriented and is equipped with a smooth volume form $dV(x)=\gamma(x)dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n$, where $\gamma(x) > 0$ is a smooth density. If $E$ is a euclidean or hermitian vector bundle, we have a Hilbert space $L^2(M,E)$ of global sections $u$ of $E$ with measurable coefficients, satisfying the $L^2$ estimate
$$||u||^2 = \int_M |u(x)|^2dV(x) < +\infty.$$

What is meant here by coefficients? If we consider a local frame $(s_1, \dots,s_r)$, there exist $(u_1, \dots,u_n)$ complex functions on $U$ such that
$$u|_U=\sum_ku_ke_k.$$
I think these $u_k$ are the coefficients, is this correct?
